# slider image appearing less in width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a newbie to web designing i was designing a web page and was facing the difficulty that the image is not appearing in full width.Please help.
Here is the Html code-

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow">
<img src="a.png">
<img src="b.jpg">
<img src="c.jpg">
</div>
```

Here is the CSS code-

```
.cycle-slideshow{
font-family:Sans-Serif;
padding:0px;
display:block;
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;
top:180px;
left:210px;

}
```

Here is the javascript used-

```
/*!
* jQuery Cycle2; version: 2.1.6 build: 20141007
* http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/
* Copyright (c) 2014 M. Alsup; Dual licensed: MIT/GPL
*/
!function(a){"use strict";function b(a){return(a||"").toLowerCase()}var c="2.1.6";a.fn.cycle=function(c){var d;return 0!==this.length||a.isReady?this.each(function(){var d,e,f,g,h=a(this),i=a.fn.cycle.log;if(!h.data("cycle.opts")){(h.data("cycle-log")===!1||c&&c.log===!1||e&&e.log===!1)&&(i=a.noop),i("--c2 init--"),d=h.data();for(var j in d)d.hasOwnProperty(j)&&/^cycle[A-Z]+/.test(j)&&(g=d[j],f=j.match(/^cycle(.*)/)[1].replace(/^[A-Z]/,b),i(f+":",g,"("+typeof g+")"),d[f]=g);e=a.extend({},a.fn.cycle.defaults,d,c||{}),e.timeoutId=0,e.paused=e.paused||!1,e.container=h,e._maxZ=e.maxZ,e.API=a.extend({_container:h},a.fn.cycle.API),e.API.log=i,e.API.trigger=function(a,b){return e.container.trigger(a,b),e.API},h.data("cycle.opts",e),h.data("cycle.API",e.API),e.API.trigger("cycle-bootstrap",[e,e.API]),e.API.addInitialSlides(),e.API.preInitSlideshow(),e.slides.length&&e.API.initSlideshow()}}):(d={s:this.selector,c:this.context},a.fn.cycle.log("requeuing slideshow (dom not ready)"),a(function(){a(d.s,d.c).cycle(c)}),this)},a.fn.cycle.API={opts:function(){return this._container.data("cycle.opts")},addInitialSlides:function(){var b=this.opts(),c=b.slides;b.slideCount=0,b.slides=a(),c=c.jquery?c:b.container.find(c),b.random&&c.sort(function(){return Math.random()-.5}),b.API.add(c)},preInitSlideshow:function(){var b=this.opts();b.API.trigger("cycle-pre-initialize",[b]);var c=a.fn.cycle.transitions[b.fx];c&&a.isFunction(c.preInit)&&c.preInit(b),b._preInitialized=!0},postInitSlideshow:function(){var b=this.opts();b.API.trigger("cycle-post-initialize",[b]);var c=a.fn.cycle.transitions[b.fx];c&&a.isFunction(c.postInit)&&c.postInit(b)},initSlideshow:function(){var b,c=this.opts(),d=c.container;c.API.calcFirstSlide(),"static"==c.container.css("position")&&c.container.css("position","relative"),a(c.slides[c.currSlide]).css({opacity:1,display:"block",visibility:"visible"}),c.API.stackSlides(c.slides[c.currSlide],c.slides[c.nextSlide],!c.reverse),c.pauseOnHover&&(c.pauseOnHover!==!0&&(d=a(c.pauseOnHover)),d.hover(function(){c.API.pause(!0)},function(){c.API.resume(!0)})),c.timeout&&(b=c.API.getSlideOpts(c.currSlide),c.API.queueTransition(b,b.timeout+c.delay)),c._initialized=!0,c.API.updateView(!0),c.API.trigger("cycle-initialized",[c]),c.API.postInitSlideshow()},pause:function(b){var c=this.opts(),d=c.API.getSlideOpts(),e=c.hoverPaused||c.paused;b?c.hoverPaused=!0:c.paused=!0,e||(c.container.addClass("cycle-paused"),c.API.trigger("cycle-paused",[c]).log("cycle-paused"),d.timeout&&(clearTimeout(c.timeoutId),c.timeoutId=0,c._remainingTimeout-=a.now()-c._lastQueue,(c._remainingTimeout<0||isNaN(c._remainingTimeout))&&(c._remainingTimeout=void 0)))},resume:function(a){var b=this.opts(),c=!b.hoverPaused&&!b.paused;a?b.hoverPaused=!1:b.paused=!1,c||(b.container.removeClass("cycle-paused"),0===b.slides.filter(":animated").length&&b.API.queueTransition(b.API.getSlideOpts(),b._remainingTimeout),b.API.trigger("cycle-resumed",[b,b._remainingTimeout]).log("cycle-resumed"))},add:function(b,c){var d,e=this.opts(),f=e.slideCount,g=!1;"string"==a.type(b)&&(b=a.trim(b)),a(b).each(function(){var b,d=a(this);c?e.container.prepend(d):e.container.append(d),e.slideCount++,b=e.API.buildSlideOpts(d),e.slides=c?a(d).add(e.slides):e.slides.add(d),e.API.initSlide(b,d,--e._maxZ),d.data("cycle.opts",b),e.API.trigger("cycle-slide-added",[e,b,d])}),e.API.updateView(!0),g=e._preInitialized&&2>f&&e.slideCount>=1,g&&(e._initialized?e.timeout&&(d=e.slides.length,e.nextSlide=e.reverse?d-1:1,e.timeoutId||e.API.queueTransition(e)):e.API.initSlideshow())},calcFirstSlide:function(){var a,b=this.opts();a=parseInt(b.startingSlide||0,10),(a>=b.slides.length||0>a)&&(a=0),b.currSlide=a,b.reverse?(b.nextSlide=a-1,b.nextSlide<0&&(b.nextSlide=b.slides.length-1)):(b.nextSlide=a+1,b.nextSlide==b.slides.length&&(b.nextSlide=0))},calcNextSlide:function(){var a,b=this.opts();b.reverse?(a=b.nextSlide-1<0,b.nextSlide=a?b.slideCount-1:b.nextSlide-1,b.currSlide=a?0:b.nextSlide+1):(a=b.nextSlide+1==b.slides.length,b.nextSlide=a?0:b.nextSlide+1,b.currSlide=a?b.slides.length-1:b.nextSlide-1)},calcTx:function(b,c){var d,e=b;return e._tempFx?d=a.fn.cycle.transitions[e._tempFx]:c&&e.manualFx&&(d=a.fn.cycle.transitions[e.manualFx]),d||(d=a.fn.cycle.transitions[e.fx]),e._tempFx=null,this.opts()._tempFx=null,d||(d=a.fn.cycle.transitions.fade,e.API.log('Transition "'+e.fx+'" not found.  Using fade.')),d},prepareTx:function(a,b){var c,d,e,f,g,h=this.opts();return h.slideCount<2?void(h.timeoutId=0):(!a||h.busy&&!h.manualTrump||(h.API.stopTransition(),h.busy=!1,clearTimeout(h.timeoutId),h.timeoutId=0),void(h.busy||(0!==h.timeoutId||a)&&(d=h.slides[h.currSlide],e=h.slides[h.nextSlide],f=h.API.getSlideOpts(h.nextSlide),g=h.API.calcTx(f,a),h._tx=g,a&&void 0!==f.manualSpeed&&(f.speed=f.manualSpeed),h.nextSlide!=h.currSlide&&(a||!h.paused&&!h.hoverPaused&&h.timeout)?(h.API.trigger("cycle-before",[f,d,e,b]),g.before&&g.before(f,d,e,b),c=function(){h.busy=!1,h.container.data("cycle.opts")&&(g.after&&g.after(f,d,e,b),h.API.trigger("cycle-after",[f,d,e,b]),h.API.queueTransition(f),h.API.updateView(!0))},h.busy=!0,g.transition?g.transition(f,d,e,b,c):h.API.doTransition(f,d,e,b,c),h.API.calcNextSlide(),h.API.updateView()):h.API.queueTransition(f))))},doTransition:function(b,c,d,e,f){var g=b,h=a(c),i=a(d),j=function(){i.animate(g.animIn||{opacity:1},g.speed,g.easeIn||g.easing,f)};i.css(g.cssBefore||{}),h.animate(g.animOut||{},g.speed,g.easeOut||g.easing,function(){h.css(g.cssAfter||{}),g.sync||j()}),g.sync&&j()},queueTransition:function(b,c){var d=this.opts(),e=void 0!==c?c:b.timeout;return 0===d.nextSlide&&0===--d.loop?(d.API.log("terminating; loop=0"),d.timeout=0,e?setTimeout(function(){d.API.trigger("cycle-finished",[d])},e):d.API.trigger("cycle-finished",[d]),void(d.nextSlide=d.currSlide)):void 0!==d.continueAuto&&(d.continueAuto===!1||a.isFunction(d.continueAuto)&&d.continueAuto()===!1)?(d.API.log("terminating automatic transitions"),d.timeout=0,void(d.timeoutId&&clearTimeout(d.timeoutId))):void(e&&(d._lastQueue=a.now(),void 0===c&&(d._remainingTimeout=b.timeout),d.paused||d.hoverPaused||(d.timeoutId=setTimeout(function(){d.API.prepareTx(!1,!d.reverse)},e))))},stopTransition:function(){var a=this.opts();a.slides.filter(":animated").length&&(a.slides.stop(!1,!0),a.API.trigger("cycle-transition-stopped",[a])),a._tx&&a._tx.stopTransition&&a._tx.stopTransition(a)},advanceSlide:function(a){var b=this.opts();return clearTimeout(b.timeoutId),b.timeoutId=0,b.nextSlide=b.currSlide+a,b.nextSlide<0?b.nextSlide=b.slides.length-1:b.nextSlide>=b.slides.length&&(b.nextSlide=0),b.API.prepareTx(!0,a>=0),!1},buildSlideOpts:function(c){var d,e,f=this.opts(),g=c.data()||{};for(var h in g)g.hasOwnProperty(h)&&/^cycle[A-Z]+/.test(h)&&(d=g[h],e=h.match(/^cycle(.*)/)[1].replace(/^[A-Z]/,b),f.API.log("["+(f.slideCount-1)+"]",e+":",d,"("+typeof d+")"),g[e]=d);g=a.extend({},a.fn.cycle.defaults,f,g),g.slideNum=f.slideCount;try{delete g.API,delete g.slideCount,delete g.currSlide,delete g.nextSlide,delete g.slides}catch(i){}return g},getSlideOpts:function(b){var c=this.opts();void 0===b&&(b=c.currSlide);var d=c.slides[b],e=a(d).data("cycle.opts");return a.extend({},c,e)},initSlide:function(b,c,d){var e=this.opts();c.css(b.slideCss||{}),d>0&&c.css("zIndex",d),isNaN(b.speed)&&(b.speed=a.fx.speeds[b.speed]||a.fx.speeds._default),b.sync||(b.speed=b.speed/2),c.addClass(e.slideClass)},updateView:function(a,b){var c=this.opts();if(c._initialized){var d=c.API.getSlideOpts(),e=c.slides[c.currSlide];!a&&b!==!0&&(c.API.trigger("cycle-update-view-before",[c,d,e]),c.updateView<0)||(c.slideActiveClass&&c.slides.removeClass(c.slideActiveClass).eq(c.currSlide).addClass(c.slideActiveClass),a&&c.hideNonActive&&c.slides.filter(":not(."+c.slideActiveClass+")").css("visibility","hidden"),0===c.updateView&&setTimeout(function(){c.API.trigger("cycle-update-view",[c,d,e,a])},d.speed/(c.sync?2:1)),0!==c.updateView&&c.API.trigger("cycle-update-view",[c,d,e,a]),a&&c.API.trigger("cycle-update-view-after",[c,d,e]))}},getComponent:function(b){var c=this.opts(),d=c[b];return"string"==typeof d?/^\s*[\>|\+|~]/.test(d)?c.container.find(d):a(d):d.jquery?d:a(d)},stackSlides:function(b,c,d){var e=this.opts();b||(b=e.slides[e.currSlide],c=e.slides[e.nextSlide],d=!e.reverse),a(b).css("zIndex",e.maxZ);var f,g=e.maxZ-2,h=e.slideCount;if(d){for(f=e.currSlide+1;h>f;f++)a(e.slides[f]).css("zIndex",g--);for(f=0;f<e.currSlide;f++)a(e.slides[f]).css("zIndex",g--)}else{for(f=e.currSlide-1;f>=0;f--)a(e.slides[f]).css("zIndex",g--);for(f=h-1;f>e.currSlide;f--)a(e.slides[f]).css("zIndex",g--)}a(c).css("zIndex",e.maxZ-1)},getSlideIndex:function(a){return this.opts().slides.index(a)}},a.fn.cycle.log=function(){window.console&&console.log&&console.log("[cycle2] "+Array.prototype.join.call(arguments," "))},a.fn.cycle.version=function(){return"Cycle2: "+c},a.fn.cycle.transitions={custom:{},none:{before:function(a,b,c,d){a.API.stackSlides(c,b,d),a.cssBefore={opacity:1,visibility:"visible",display:"block"}}},fade:{before:function(b,c,d,e){var f=b.API.getSlideOpts(b.nextSlide).slideCss||{};b.API.stackSlides(c,d,e),b.cssBefore=a.extend(f,{opacity:0,visibility:"visible",display:"block"}),b.animIn={opacity:1},b.animOut={opacity:0}}},fadeout:{before:function(b,c,d,e){var f=b.API.getSlideOpts(b.nextSlide).slideCss||{};b.API.stackSlides(c,d,e),b.cssBefore=a.extend(f,{opacity:1,visibility:"visible",display:"block"}),b.animOut={opacity:0}}},scrollHorz:{before:function(a,b,c,d){a.API.stackSlides(b,c,d);var e=a.container.css("overflow","hidden").width();a.cssBefore={left:d?e:-e,top:0,opacity:1,visibility:"visible",display:"block"},a.cssAfter={zIndex:a._maxZ-2,left:0},a.animIn={left:0},a.animOut={left:d?-e:e}}}},a.fn.cycle.defaults={allowWrap:!0,autoSelector:".cycle-slideshow[data-cycle-auto-init!=false]",delay:0,easing:null,fx:"fade",hideNonActive:!0,loop:0,manualFx:void 0,manualSpeed:void 0,manualTrump:!0,maxZ:100,pauseOnHover:!1,reverse:!1,slideActiveClass:"cycle-slide-active",slideClass:"cycle-slide",slideCss:{position:"absolute",top:0,left:0},slides:"> img",speed:500,startingSlide:0,sync:!0,timeout:4e3,updateView:0},a(document).ready(function(){a(a.fn.cycle.defaults.autoSelector).cycle()})}(jQuery),/*! Cycle2 autoheight plugin; Copyright (c) M.Alsup, 2012; version: 20130913 */
function(a){"use strict";function b(b,d){var e,f,g,h=d.autoHeight;if("container"==h)f=a(d.slides[d.currSlide]).outerHeight(),d.container.height(f);else if(d._autoHeightRatio)d.container.height(d.container.width()/d._autoHeightRatio);else if("calc"===h||"number"==a.type(h)&&h>=0){if(g="calc"===h?c(b,d):h>=d.slides.length?0:h,g==d._sentinelIndex)return;d._sentinelIndex=g,d._sentinel&&d._sentinel.remove(),e=a(d.slides[g].cloneNode(!0)),e.removeAttr("id name rel").find("[id],[name],[rel]").removeAttr("id name rel"),e.css({position:"static",visibility:"hidden",display:"block"}).prependTo(d.container).addClass("cycle-sentinel cycle-slide").removeClass("cycle-slide-active"),e.find("*").css("visibility","hidden"),d._sentinel=e}}function c(b,c){var d=0,e=-1;return c.slides.each(function(b){var c=a(this).height();c>e&&(e=c,d=b)}),d}function d(b,c,d,e){var f=a(e).outerHeight();c.container.animate({height:f},c.autoHeightSpeed,c.autoHeightEasing)}function e(c,f){f._autoHeightOnResize&&(a(window).off("resize orientationchange",f._autoHeightOnResize),f._autoHeightOnResize=null),f.container.off("cycle-slide-added cycle-slide-removed",b),f.container.off("cycle-destroyed",e),f.container.off("cycle-before",d),f._sentinel&&(f._sentinel.remove(),f._sentinel=null)}a.extend(a.fn.cycle.defaults,{autoHeight:0,autoHeightSpeed:250,autoHeightEasing:null}),a(document).on("cycle-initialized",function(c,f){function g(){b(c,f)}var h,i=f.autoHeight,j=a.type(i),k=null;("string"===j||"number"===j)&&(f.container.on("cycle-slide-added cycle-slide-removed",b),f.container.on("cycle-destroyed",e),"container"==i?f.container.on("cycle-before",d):"string"===j&&/\d+\:\d+/.test(i)&&(h=i.match(/(\d+)\:(\d+)/),h=h[1]/h[2],f._autoHeightRatio=h),"number"!==j&&(f._autoHeightOnResize=function(){clearTimeout(k),k=setTimeout(g,50)},a(window).on("resize orientationchange",f._autoHeightOnResize)),setTimeout(g,30))})}(jQuery),/*! caption plugin for Cycle2;  version: 20130306 */
function(a){"use strict";a.extend(a.fn.cycle.defaults,{caption:"> .cycle-caption",captionTemplate:"{{slideNum}} / {{slideCount}}",overlay:"> .cycle-overlay",overlayTemplate:"<div>{{title}}</div><div>{{desc}}</div>",captionModule:"caption"}),a(document).on("cycle-update-view",function(b,c,d,e){if("caption"===c.captionModule){a.each(["caption","overlay"],function(){var a=this,b=d[a+"Template"],f=c.API.getComponent(a);f.length&&b?(f.html(c.API.tmpl(b,d,c,e)),f.show()):f.hide()})}}),a(document).on("cycle-destroyed",function(b,c){var d;a.each(["caption","overlay"],function(){var a=this,b=c[a+"Template"];c[a]&&b&&(d=c.API.getComponent("caption"),d.empty())})})}(jQuery),/*! command plugin for Cycle2;  version: 20140415 */
function(a){"use strict";var b=a.fn.cycle;a.fn.cycle=function(c){var d,e,f,g=a.makeArray(arguments);return"number"==a.type(c)?this.cycle("goto",c):"string"==a.type(c)?this.each(function(){var h;return d=c,f=a(this).data("cycle.opts"),void 0===f?void b.log('slideshow must be initialized before sending commands; "'+d+'" ignored'):(d="goto"==d?"jump":d,e=f.API[d],a.isFunction(e)?(h=a.makeArray(g),h.shift(),e.apply(f.API,h)):void b.log("unknown command: ",d))}):b.apply(this,arguments)},a.extend(a.fn.cycle,b),a.extend(b.API,{next:function(){var a=this.opts();if(!a.busy||a.manualTrump){var b=a.reverse?-1:1;a.allowWrap===!1&&a.currSlide+b>=a.slideCount||(a.API.advanceSlide(b),a.API.trigger("cycle-next",[a]).log("cycle-next"))}},prev:function(){var a=this.opts();if(!a.busy||a.manualTrump){var b=a.reverse?1:-1;a.allowWrap===!1&&a.currSlide+b<0||(a.API.advanceSlide(b),a.API.trigger("cycle-prev",[a]).log("cycle-prev"))}},destroy:function(){this.stop();var b=this.opts(),c=a.isFunction(a._data)?a._data:a.noop;clearTimeout(b.timeoutId),b.timeoutId=0,b.API.stop(),b.API.trigger("cycle-destroyed",[b]).log("cycle-destroyed"),b.container.removeData(),c(b.container[0],"parsedAttrs",!1),b.retainStylesOnDestroy||(b.container.removeAttr("style"),b.slides.removeAttr("style"),b.slides.removeClass(b.slideActiveClass)),b.slides.each(function(){var d=a(this);d.removeData(),d.removeClass(b.slideClass),c(this,"parsedAttrs",!1)})},jump:function(a,b){var c,d=this.opts();if(!d.busy||d.manualTrump){var e=parseInt(a,10);if(isNaN(e)||0>e||e>=d.slides.length)return void d.API.log("goto: invalid slide index: "+e);if(e==d.currSlide)return void d.API.log("goto: skipping, already on slide",e);d.nextSlide=e,clearTimeout(d.timeoutId),d.timeoutId=0,d.API.log("goto: ",e," (zero-index)"),c=d.currSlide<d.nextSlide,d._tempFx=b,d.API.prepareTx(!0,c)}},stop:function(){var b=this.opts(),c=b.container;clearTimeout(b.timeoutId),b.timeoutId=0,b.API.stopTransition(),b.pauseOnHover&&(b.pauseOnHover!==!0&&(c=a(b.pauseOnHover)),c.off("mouseenter mouseleave")),b.API.trigger("cycle-stopped",[b]).log("cycle-stopped")},reinit:function(){var a=this.opts();a.API.destroy(),a.container.cycle()},remove:function(b){for(var c,d,e=this.opts(),f=[],g=1,h=0;h<e.slides.length;h++)c=e.slides[h],h==b?d=c:(f.push(c),a(c).data("cycle.opts").slideNum=g,g++);d&&(e.slides=a(f),e.slideCount--,a(d).remove(),b==e.currSlide?e.API.advanceSlide(1):b<e.currSlide?e.currSlide--:e.currSlide++,e.API.trigger("cycle-slide-removed",[e,b,d]).log("cycle-slide-removed"),e.API.updateView())}}),a(document).on("click.cycle","[data-cycle-cmd]",function(b){b.preventDefault();var c=a(this),d=c.data("cycle-cmd"),e=c.data("cycle-context")||".cycle-slideshow";a(e).cycle(d,c.data("cycle-arg"))})}(jQuery),/*! hash plugin for Cycle2;  version: 20130905 */
function(a){"use strict";function b(b,c){var d;return b._hashFence?void(b._hashFence=!1):(d=window.location.hash.substring(1),void b.slides.each(function(e){if(a(this).data("cycle-hash")==d){if(c===!0)b.startingSlide=e;else{var f=b.currSlide<e;b.nextSlide=e,b.API.prepareTx(!0,f)}return!1}}))}a(document).on("cycle-pre-initialize",function(c,d){b(d,!0),d._onHashChange=function(){b(d,!1)},a(window).on("hashchange",d._onHashChange)}),a(document).on("cycle-update-view",function(a,b,c){c.hash&&"#"+c.hash!=window.location.hash&&(b._hashFence=!0,window.location.hash=c.hash)}),a(document).on("cycle-destroyed",function(b,c){c._onHashChange&&a(window).off("hashchange",c._onHashChange)})}(jQuery),/*! loader plugin for Cycle2;  version: 20131121 */
function(a){"use strict";a.extend(a.fn.cycle.defaults,{loader:!1}),a(document).on("cycle-bootstrap",function(b,c){function d(b,d){function f(b){var f;"wait"==c.loader?(h.push(b),0===j&&(h.sort(g),e.apply(c.API,[h,d]),c.container.removeClass("cycle-loading"))):(f=a(c.slides[c.currSlide]),e.apply(c.API,[b,d]),f.show(),c.container.removeClass("cycle-loading"))}function g(a,b){return a.data("index")-b.data("index")}var h=[];if("string"==a.type(b))b=a.trim(b);else if("array"===a.type(b))for(var i=0;i<b.length;i++)b[i]=a(b[i])[0];b=a(b);var j=b.length;j&&(b.css("visibility","hidden").appendTo("body").each(function(b){function g(){0===--i&&(--j,f(k))}var i=0,k=a(this),l=k.is("img")?k:k.find("img");return k.data("index",b),l=l.filter(":not(.cycle-loader-ignore)").filter(':not([src=""])'),l.length?(i=l.length,void l.each(function(){this.complete?g():a(this).load(function(){g()}).on("error",function(){0===--i&&(c.API.log("slide skipped; img not loaded:",this.src),0===--j&&"wait"==c.loader&&e.apply(c.API,[h,d]))})})):(--j,void h.push(k))}),j&&c.container.addClass("cycle-loading"))}var e;c.loader&&(e=c.API.add,c.API.add=d)})}(jQuery),/*! pager plugin for Cycle2;  version: 20140415 */
function(a){"use strict";function b(b,c,d){var e,f=b.API.getComponent("pager");f.each(function(){var f=a(this);if(c.pagerTemplate){var g=b.API.tmpl(c.pagerTemplate,c,b,d[0]);e=a(g).appendTo(f)}else e=f.children().eq(b.slideCount-1);e.on(b.pagerEvent,function(a){b.pagerEventBubble||a.preventDefault(),b.API.page(f,a.currentTarget)})})}function c(a,b){var c=this.opts();if(!c.busy||c.manualTrump){var d=a.children().index(b),e=d,f=c.currSlide<e;c.currSlide!=e&&(c.nextSlide=e,c._tempFx=c.pagerFx,c.API.prepareTx(!0,f),c.API.trigger("cycle-pager-activated",[c,a,b]))}}a.extend(a.fn.cycle.defaults,{pager:"> .cycle-pager",pagerActiveClass:"cycle-pager-active",pagerEvent:"click.cycle",pagerEventBubble:void 0,pagerTemplate:"<span>&bull;</span>"}),a(document).on("cycle-bootstrap",function(a,c,d){d.buildPagerLink=b}),a(document).on("cycle-slide-added",function(a,b,d,e){b.pager&&(b.API.buildPagerLink(b,d,e),b.API.page=c)}),a(document).on("cycle-slide-removed",function(b,c,d){if(c.pager){var e=c.API.getComponent("pager");e.each(function(){var b=a(this);a(b.children()[d]).remove()})}}),a(document).on("cycle-update-view",function(b,c){var d;c.pager&&(d=c.API.getComponent("pager"),d.each(function(){a(this).children().removeClass(c.pagerActiveClass).eq(c.currSlide).addClass(c.pagerActiveClass)}))}),a(document).on("cycle-destroyed",function(a,b){var c=b.API.getComponent("pager");c&&(c.children().off(b.pagerEvent),b.pagerTemplate&&c.empty())})}(jQuery),/*! prevnext plugin for Cycle2;  version: 20140408 */
function(a){"use strict";a.extend(a.fn.cycle.defaults,{next:"> .cycle-next",nextEvent:"click.cycle",disabledClass:"disabled",prev:"> .cycle-prev",prevEvent:"click.cycle",swipe:!1}),a(document).on("cycle-initialized",function(a,b){if(b.API.getComponent("next").on(b.nextEvent,function(a){a.preventDefault(),b.API.next()}),b.API.getComponent("prev").on(b.prevEvent,function(a){a.preventDefault(),b.API.prev()}),b.swipe){var c=b.swipeVert?"swipeUp.cycle":"swipeLeft.cycle swipeleft.cycle",d=b.swipeVert?"swipeDown.cycle":"swipeRight.cycle swiperight.cycle";b.container.on(c,function(){b._tempFx=b.swipeFx,b.API.next()}),b.container.on(d,function(){b._tempFx=b.swipeFx,b.API.prev()})}}),a(document).on("cycle-update-view",function(a,b){if(!b.allowWrap){var c=b.disabledClass,d=b.API.getComponent("next"),e=b.API.getComponent("prev"),f=b._prevBoundry||0,g=void 0!==b._nextBoundry?b._nextBoundry:b.slideCount-1;b.currSlide==g?d.addClass(c).prop("disabled",!0):d.removeClass(c).prop("disabled",!1),b.currSlide===f?e.addClass(c).prop("disabled",!0):e.removeClass(c).prop("disabled",!1)}}),a(document).on("cycle-destroyed",function(a,b){b.API.getComponent("prev").off(b.nextEvent),b.API.getComponent("next").off(b.prevEvent),b.container.off("swipeleft.cycle swiperight.cycle swipeLeft.cycle swipeRight.cycle swipeUp.cycle swipeDown.cycle")})}(jQuery),/*! progressive loader plugin for Cycle2;  version: 20130315 */
function(a){"use strict";a.extend(a.fn.cycle.defaults,{progressive:!1}),a(document).on("cycle-pre-initialize",function(b,c){if(c.progressive){var d,e,f=c.API,g=f.next,h=f.prev,i=f.prepareTx,j=a.type(c.progressive);if("array"==j)d=c.progressive;else if(a.isFunction(c.progressive))d=c.progressive(c);else if("string"==j){if(e=a(c.progressive),d=a.trim(e.html()),!d)return;if(/^(\[)/.test(d))try{d=a.parseJSON(d)}catch(k){return void f.log("error parsing progressive slides",k)}else d=d.split(new RegExp(e.data("cycle-split")||"\n")),d[d.length-1]||d.pop()}i&&(f.prepareTx=function(a,b){var e,f;return a||0===d.length?void i.apply(c.API,[a,b]):void(b&&c.currSlide==c.slideCount-1?(f=d[0],d=d.slice(1),c.container.one("cycle-slide-added",function(a,b){setTimeout(function(){b.API.advanceSlide(1)},50)}),c.API.add(f)):b||0!==c.currSlide?i.apply(c.API,[a,b]):(e=d.length-1,f=d[e],d=d.slice(0,e),c.container.one("cycle-slide-added",function(a,b){setTimeout(function(){b.currSlide=1,b.API.advanceSlide(-1)},50)}),c.API.add(f,!0)))}),g&&(f.next=function(){var a=this.opts();if(d.length&&a.currSlide==a.slideCount-1){var b=d[0];d=d.slice(1),a.container.one("cycle-slide-added",function(a,b){g.apply(b.API),b.container.removeClass("cycle-loading")}),a.container.addClass("cycle-loading"),a.API.add(b)}else g.apply(a.API)}),h&&(f.prev=function(){var a=this.opts();if(d.length&&0===a.currSlide){var b=d.length-1,c=d[b];d=d.slice(0,b),a.container.one("cycle-slide-added",function(a,b){b.currSlide=1,b.API.advanceSlide(-1),b.container.removeClass("cycle-loading")}),a.container.addClass("cycle-loading"),a.API.add(c,!0)}else h.apply(a.API)})}})}(jQuery),/*! tmpl plugin for Cycle2;  version: 20121227 */
function(a){"use strict";a.extend(a.fn.cycle.defaults,{tmplRegex:"{{((.)?.*?)}}"}),a.extend(a.fn.cycle.API,{tmpl:function(b,c){var d=new RegExp(c.tmplRegex||a.fn.cycle.defaults.tmplRegex,"g"),e=a.makeArray(arguments);return e.shift(),b.replace(d,function(b,c){var d,f,g,h,i=c.split(".");for(d=0;d<e.length;d++)if(g=e[d]){if(i.length>1)for(h=g,f=0;f<i.length;f++)g=h,h=h[i[f]]||c;else h=g[c];if(a.isFunction(h))return h.apply(g,e);if(void 0!==h&&null!==h&&h!=c)return h}return c})}})}(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this property to your css class

```
width:100%;
```

Ps: Your javascript code is unreadable

Comment: Thanks man!But width 100% is not working The image is still cut from the left side

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, but your div don't have dimensions and is 0x0 pixels width x height.
Add this to your css:

```
 width:400px;
 height:300px;
```

Here is a fiddle where it's running ok.

https://jsfiddle.net/oenbsekx/

Good luck